# Referencing addins from secondary script file

Tags: cakebuild

I have a cake file with my Tasks defined. 
I also have a second cake file with some classes defined. 
In the second file, I would like to reference e.g. Cake.Json, and maybe Cake.Svn. But I cannot figure out how reference them.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both addins and utility Cake scripts are references using pre-processor directives.

## Addin directive

#### Usage

```
#addin nuget:?package={NuGet Package Id}&version={NuGet package version}
```

#### Example:

```
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Json&version=3.0.1
```

## Reference directive

#### Usage

```
#r "Path to assembly / dll"
```

#### Example:

```
#r "bin/Cake.Json.dll"
```

## Load directive

#### Usage

```
#load "Path to cake file"
```

#### Example:

```
#load "scripts/common.cake"
```

## Reference

Read more about pre-processor directives at

https://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/preprocessor-directives

Comment: Yes, I get that. But do I need to have them in both files? Both the main script with the Tasks and in the secondary script with class definitions?

Comment: Scripts are merged so it depends. You'll at least need it in the script that uses the addin. If both use addin then only initating script needs it.

Comment: Hm. It will at the very least break intellisense, but that would be a small price if it works. If I put the class definitions into the main script, where would I put them? At the bottom?